# how to not set to history list when open a new Tab on browser with javascript?

Tags: c#, javascript, php

I have a question about Javascript about opening a new tab on asp environment.

```
 function LoginDrupal() {
            var username = document.getElementById('<%=txtUsername.ClientID%>').value;
            var password = document.getElementById('<%=txtPassword.ClientID%>').value;
            window.open("http://example.com/login.php","_blank");
            self.focus();
        }
```

then on http://example.com/login.php i have a code like this.

```
<?php 
// other stuff
echo "<script>window.close();</script>"; 
?>
```

so, after a new tab appear, suddenly the tab was closed automatically. the problem is, http://example.com/login.php was create on history list.

Is there any way to extend my code to remove that path to history list? or i must consider what browser which i use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot remove the entry from the history, and you cannot prevent it from being added to the history. What you can do is replacing the last entry with the next page using `window.location.replace('url');`.